# Is the seconds cancel out in equation?

Tags: kinematics, units, dimensional-analysis

Do the seconds cancel out in this equation leaving seconds  instead of seconds squared?

[image]

Comment: $s^{-2}×s=s^{-1}$ ...

Comment: Yes they do, as Nehal Sammee has demonstrated. In my opinion it's a good thing to include units when you substitute data into an equation, and to simplify the units at the end, treating them like algebraic symbols. It's a good check on your maths. In the case you've presented, it's re-assuring that the final unit is what it should be: m/s.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

yes, the second cancel the second square leaving it only second
More Explanation:
v0 + at = m⁄s + (m/s^2)(s)"the s cancels the square leaving it only s"= m⁄s + m/s
For example: 4/2^2 x 2 = 4/4 x 2 =8/4 = 4/2